# How to include a grand total count along with pagination and sorting?

Tags: postgresql

Have a PostgreSQL function `findbooks()` accepts params for WHERE, OFFSET and LIMIT, dynamically builds a `SELECT` returning rows, for example

```
create or replace sa.findbooks(...) returns SETOF sa.books language 'plpgsql'
as $$
declare dynamicsql text;
begin
  if ... then
    dynamicsql := 'select ...';
  end if;
  execute dynamicsql;
end;
$$
```

Supposed the frontend wants to show how many total books met criteria BEFORE pagination. One way I can think of is to append a new column for this piece of info, obviously all cells of this column will have the same repeated value. Is there any better way?

PostgreSQL v12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the total count, there is no better way than to execute an extra query that counts the data you want. This will be inefficient, but then paging with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` is inefficient too, so it might not matter too much.